# Can you start a Scala REPL in SBT when compilation is broken?

Tags: scala, sbt

When your project doesn't compile, can you start a Scala REPL in SBT? using `sbt console` SBT seems to first compile the project and exit in this case. However the console could help experiment for solving the compilation trouble....

Comment: You can just type sbt and enter the console, it won't compile anything unless you want to.

Comment: Hmmm not in my sbtVersion 0.13.1. I'll pick inside my build.sbt then...

Comment: Sorry I think I misread your question, I don't think you can start a REPL inside sbt, the REPL is something different, what you can do is access the sbt console by simply typing sbt and then do what you want, but that's as far as it can get as far as I know.

Comment: Well, the SBT console is not a Scala REPL, is it

Comment: I'd like to be able to do this too! Although your own project will be in a unknown state after a failed compile, it's nice to have a REPL with all of the dependencies in the classpath.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`consoleQuick` is an SBT task that starts a REPL with the same classpath as `console` but without forcing compilation. (It is described alongside similar tasks by the `sbt tasks` command).